# Complete value from the drop down not appearing in mat-option in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an array of object coming from file `en_US_file.json` which has below

```
"streetList": [
      {
        "value": "",
        "street": ""
      },
      {
        "value": "AVE",
        "street": "Avenue"
      },
      {
        "value": "BLVD",
        "street": "Boulevard"
      },
      {
        "value": "CT",
        "street": "Court"
      }
      ]
```

which displays the street type as below in drop down
[image]

and once I select Eg: BLVD the selected is being shown as below which is fine
[image]

and the HTML code for it is as below

```
<div class="col col-4">
{{ interceptContext.streetType }}
<p>
<mat-select formControlName="streetType"(selectionChange)="onSelectChange($event.value)">
<mat-option *ngFor="let streetTypeObj of Contextlst.streetList" [value]="streetTypeObj.value">
{{streetTypeObj.value !== "" ? ((streetTypeObj.value === selectedOption) ? streetTypeObj.value  : streetTypeObj.value + ': ' + streetTypeObj.street) : ''}}
</mat-option>
</mat-select>
</p>
</div>
```

.ts code is as below

```
  onSelectChange(value: any) {
    this.selectedOption = value;
  }

this.Contextlst = en_US_file.streetList; // similar addition is ts to call the .json file
```

I want to display the dropdown as above but once I select some value among AVE, BLVD, CT ... Eg: BLVD the display is as below, when I click again the dropdown

[image]

which I don't want and want to show the whole filed as `BLVD: Boulevard` .

How can I do it ?

Comment: If you don't want to modify the rendered options then why modify them inside the template interpolation? You could simply do: `{{ streetTypeObj.value + ': ' + streetTypeObj.street }}`.

Comment: In that case, the display will be showing `BLVD: Boulevard` instead of `BLVD`, which I don't want to happen.

I wan to show `BLVD` once i selected and when clicked on the dropdown it should show  `BLVD: Boulevard`

Comment: @user9414660 https://angular-ivy-psm6wa.stackblitz.io/ is this what do you want ?

Comment: @user9414660 can you confirm its working for you or not https://angular-ivy-psm6wa.stackblitz.io/